# How to speed up the relationship creation with match...create

Tags: neo4j

I'm creating nodes and relationships programmatically using **neo4j java driver** based on reading the relationships specified in a **csv file**.

The csv file contains about **16 million rows** and there will be about **16*4 million relationships** to create.

I'm using the pattern `Match Match Create` for this purpose :

```
Match (a:label), (b:label) where a.prop='1234' and b.prop='4567' create (a)-[:LINKS]->(b)
```

I just started the program and functionally it ran well. I saw nodes and relationships being created properly in the neo4j DB.

However, for the past four hours, only 100,000 rows from the csv have been processed and only 92037 relationships being created.

According to this speed, it will take about one months to finish processing the csv and creating all the relationships.

I noticed that I was sending the `Match...Create` one by one to the **session.writeTransaction()**.

Is there any way to batch them up so as to speed up the creation time?

Comment: Do you have indexes on :label(prop)? If not then your query is performing an all nodes scan for both `a` and `b` for every row. Can you provide the query plan from an EXPLAIN of the query (after expanding all elements of the plan)? And the query itself?

Comment: Why you are not using the `LOAD CSV` feature of Cypher ? The `periodic commit` comes for free with it, so it's really to bacth the modification.